# python class attribute editing

Tags: python, class-attributes

i try to write a template class in python. my aim is importing this class for other projects.
class have a class attribute `M`. it's default value is zero. when i import class in other project i change `M`  with a new value. after that, i sampling class but instance attributes dont change. they consider zero value for `M`. how can i solve this problem? i dont want to use instance attribute for 'M'.

```
import numpy as np
class Example():
    M=0
    matrix=np.ones((M,M))
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.operate()
    def operate(self):
        Example.matrix=Example.matrix*self.a*self.b
        print(Example.matrix)
Example.M=5
m1=Example(3,5)
```

when i run the code,
`[]` is the result.
but i expect this matrix:

> [[15. 15. 15. 15. 15.]
> [15. 15. 15. 15. 15.]
> [15. 15. 15. 15. 15.]
> [15. 15. 15. 15. 15.]
> [15. 15. 15. 15. 15.]]

Comment: The line `matrix=np.ones((M,M))` only gets evaluated once.  That is when the class Example is defined.  When you set `Example.M=5` that will update the class attribute, but it doesn't reinvoke the `np.ones` line.  Similarly, `Example(3,5)` invokes the `Example.__init__` method, but id does not invoke the `np.ones` line either.

Comment: If you need a side effect of resetting `Example.M` it would be best to make a `resize` method that changes `Example.M` and reinitializes the matrix.

Comment: An instance method mutating a class attribute is odd-looking enough that I suspect this is an XY problem. What is this class supposed to encapsulate or represent? What do you do with `m1` after it gets created, what happens if you create multiple instance of `Example`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the definition of your `matrix` inside the `__init__` function - right now, the class is parsed, `M` is set to `0` and `matrix` is set to `np.ones(0,0)` which is an empty list `[]`. Then, you assign `5` to `M`, but `matrix` remains unchanged.

So you need to either redefine `matrix` manually:

```py
Example.M = 5
Example.matrix = np.ones(Example.M, Example.M)
```

or you define a class method and use that set `M`:

```py
class Example():
    M=0
    matrix=np.ones((M,M))
    @classmethod
    def setM(m):
        Example.M = m
```

or you move the definition of `matrix` inside the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `matrix` is decrlared once, if you try to modify `M`, it doesn't change the `matrix`.

By changing the code a bit, this gives:

```python
import numpy as np
class Example():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.M=5
        self.matrix=np.ones((self.M,self.M))
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.operate()
    def operate(self):
        self.matrix=self.matrix*self.a*self.b
        print(self.matrix)
Example.M=5
m1=Example(3,5)
```

Basically, I moved `M` and `matrix` to `__init__`, changed `M` to `self.M` and `matrix` to `self.matrix`.